# Devise login succeed when not confirmed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise, ruby-on-rails-3

Could you tell me how to integrate the confirmed? attribute into the session-login process?

I've set up a working app with devise with confirmable and authenticatable enabled...
But I can log in with a user-model that isn't confirmed!

***UPDATE***

I've commented on the confirmable-section in my migration.

```
  # schema.rb
  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                                        :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",            :limit => 128, :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "password_salt",                                :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    ....
  end

# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, 
         :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :token_authenticatable
  ...
end

# routes.rb
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :passwords => "password_resets" } do
  # this doesn't matter to my mentioned problem
  get "instruction", :to => "password_resets#instruction", :path => "/users/password/instruction", :as => "instruction_user_password"
end
```

Comment: Make your you are uncommenting these symbols in the migration when you initially create your user.

Comment: I have uncommented them - see my schema above...

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Show us how you've set up a working app. What is in the User model?

Comment: Checks devise if the user is confirmed before logging in automatically? I didn't find anything in the devise-source on github?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

argh...

I set the wrong configuration in **devise.rb**

```
  # ==> Configuration for :confirmable
  # The time you want to give your user to confirm his account. During this time
  # he will be able to access your application without confirming. The default is nil.
  # When confirm_within is zero, the user won't be able to sign in without confirming. 
  # You can use this to let your user access some features of your application 
  # without confirming the account, but blocking it after a certain period 
  # (ie 2 days). 
  config.confirm_within = 2.days

  # I didn't read that the user has access at this time
```